# Vuex 4 in vue composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vuex4

I am running to a problem where my user object is not being populated in time for the rest of my component to use it. In vuex, I am dispatching an action where I call the fetchAuthUser. The following is the store for User

```
import axios from "axios";

const state = () => ({
    user: null,
    userStatus: null
})

const getters = {
    authUser: state => {
        return state.user
    }
}

const actions = {
    async fetchAuthUser({commit}) {
        await axios.get('/auth-user')
            .then(res => {
                commit('setAuthUser', res.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Unable to fetch auth user');
            });
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setAuthUser(state, user) {
        state.user = user
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,

}
```

No in my component I am calling the following

```
store.dispatch('User/fetchAuthUser');
const user = computed(() => {
  return store.getters['User/authUser'];
});
```

Whenever I try to access the user object to get a list of posts that are assigned to the user, the user object is always null, meaning it's not populated prior to using it.

```
store.dispatch("Posts/fetchUserPosts", user.data.user_id);
```

I have the async and the await on the fetchAuthUser function, so why does the code to fetch the posts still executes

So how can I get the use robjet populated before it gets accessed.

the following is my component code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import {computed, defineComponent, onBeforeMount} from "vue";
import {useStore} from "vuex";
import {Head} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/Community/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
import Post from "@/Pages/Community/Post.vue";

defineComponent({Post})

const store = useStore();

store.dispatch('User/fetchAuthUser');
const user = computed(() => {
  return store.getters['User/authUser'];
});


  store.dispatch("Posts/fetchUserPosts", user.data.user_id);

  const posts = computed(() => store.getters["Posts/posts"]);
  const newsStatus = computed(() => store.getters["Posts/newsStatus"]);

  const friendButtonText = computed(() => {
    return store.getters["Profile/friendButtonText"]
  })

  const friendship = computed(() => {
    return store.getters["Profile/friendship"]
  })

  const sendFriendRequest = (friendId: number) => {
    store.dispatch('Profile/SendFriendRequest', friendId)
  }

  const acceptFriendRequest = (userId: number) => {
    store.dispatch('Profile/AcceptFriendRequest', userId);
  }

  const ignoreFriendRequest = (userId: number) => {
    store.dispatch('Profile/IgnoreFriendRequest', userId);
  }

  const unfriend = (friendId: number) => {
    store.dispatch('Profile/Unfriend', friendId);

  }




</script>

<template>
  <Head title="Profile"/>
  <AuthenticatedLayout>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center" v-if="user">
      <div class="relative mb-8">
        <div class="w-100 h-64 z-10 overflow-hidden">
          <img
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2662116/pexels-photo-2662116.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
              alt="" class="object-cover w-full">
        </div>
        <div class="absolute flex items-center bottom-0 left-0 ml-12 -mb-8 z-20">
          <div class="w-32">
            <img
                src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/portrait-white-man-isolated_53876-40306.jpg?w=996&t=st=1687871471~exp=1687872071~hmac=4e38748c6d278550acda8ec15451c5f1798d86a82fc03d13e41835cfa3f25cf3"
                alt="" class="object-cover w-32 h-32 border-4 border-gray-200 rounded-full shadow-lg">
          </div>
          <p class="ml-4 text-2xl text-gray-100">{{ user.data.attributes.name }}</p>
        </div>
                        <div class="absolute flex items-center bottom-0 right-0 mr-12 mb-4 z-20" v-if="friendButtonText && friendButtonText === 'Add Friend'">
                            <button class="py-1 px-3 bg-gray-400 rounded" @click.prevent="sendFriendRequest(user.data.user_id)">{{ friendButtonText }}</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="absolute flex items-center bottom-0 right-0 mr-12 mb-4 z-20" v-if="friendButtonText && friendButtonText === 'Pending Friend Request'">
                            <button class="py-1 px-3 bg-gray-400 rounded" @click.prevent="unfriend(friendship.data.attributes.friend_id)">{{ friendButtonText }}</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="absolute flex items-center bottom-0 right-0 mr-12 mb-4 z-20" v-if="friendButtonText && friendButtonText === 'Unfriend'">
                            <button class="py-1 px-3 bg-gray-400 rounded" @click.prevent="unfriend(friendship.data.attributes.friend_id)">{{ friendButtonText }}</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="absolute flex items-center bottom-0 right-0 mr-12 mb-4 z-20" v-if="friendButtonText && friendButtonText === 'Accept'">
                            <button class="mr-2 py-1 px-3 bg-blue-500 rounded" @click.prevent="acceptFriendRequest(user.data.user_id)">Accept</button>
                            <button class="py-1 px-3 bg-gray-400 rounded" @click.prevent="ignoreFriendRequest(user.data.user_id)">Ignore</button>
                        </div>

      </div>

                  <p v-if="newsStatus.postsStatus === 'loading'">Loading posts...</p>
                  <Post v-else v-for="(post, postKey) in posts.data" :key="postKey" :post="post"/>

    </div>


  </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Do you get the data successfully from api?

Comment: Yes it is successfully retrieved

Comment: This `defineComponent({Post})` serves no good purpose, but isn't related to the problem you describe. `store.dispatch("Posts/fetchUserPosts", user.data.user_id);` - this is a mistake. You need to wait for the previous action to complete. First of all detached promises shouldn't be in setup body, either use await and make the comp use suspense, or move them to onMounted. Should be `await store.dispatch(...); await store.dispatch(...)` in the end. `.catch(` is not a good idea because early catch will continue normal execution, while it's not normal